# disable-output-escaping broken with libxslt library on MacOS Catalina

Tags: xml, macos, macos-catalina, libxslt

A curious problem after upgrading to MacOS Catalina and linking against the libxslt and libxml2 included in the 10.15 SDK, is that all uses of `disable-output-escaping="yes"` are broken and escape the output anyway.  A couple examples from various XSLT sheets:

```xml
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;--test comment--&gt;</xsl:text>
<xsl:value-of select="/*[1]/LBL_CM_3" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
```

Where the `LBL_CM_3` node has some HTML in it, e.g. `cm<sup>3</sup>`.  Both of these cases are escaped (unexpected result) when processed by my code, using very straight-forward API use.  Here is a stripped down version with error checking and cleanup omitted:

```cpp
    xmlDocPtr tmpXmlDoc = xmlParseMemory(inputString.c_str(), (int)inputString.size());
    xmlDocPtr tmpXslDoc = xmlParseMemory(xslInputStr, xslInputStrSize);
    xsltStylesheetPtr tmpXslStyleSheet = xsltParseStylesheetDoc(tmpXslDoc);
    xmlDocPtr tmpHtmlDoc = xsltApplyStylesheet(tmpXslStyleSheet, tmpXmlDoc, params);
```

However, if I process the same input and stylesheet using `/usr/bin/xsltproc`, the output is not escaped (expected result).  We both link the same library on the system:

```sh
$ otool -L /usr/bin/xsltproc | grep -E 'xml|xslt'
/usr/bin/xsltproc:
    /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.15.0)
    /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.26.0)
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
$ otool -L TestXslt.app/Contents/MacOS/TestXslt | grep -E 'xml|xslt'
    /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
    /usr/lib/libexslt.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.15.0)
    /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.26.0)
```

The system `xsltproc` version info:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/xsltproc --version
Using libxml 20904, libxslt 10129 and libexslt 817
xsltproc was compiled against libxml 20904, libxslt 10129 and libexslt 817
libxslt 10129 was compiled against libxml 20904
libexslt 817 was compiled against libxml 20904
```

The 10.15 SDK `usr/include/libxml/xmlversion.h` shows the same version:

```cpp
/**
 * LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION:
 *
 * the version string like "1.2.3"
 */
#define LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION "2.9.4"

/**
 * LIBXML_VERSION:
 *
 * the version number: 1.2.3 value is 10203
 */
#define LIBXML_VERSION 20904
```

This worked as expected previously with the MacOS Sierra SDK, with the same calling code and same XSLT sheets.  All the rest of the XSLT processing appears to be working as expected, only `disable-output-escaping="yes"` is being ignored.

Comment: Not really relevant, but disable-output-escaping should be a last resort, and using it in place of xsl:comment to output a comment, as in your first example, is thoroughly bad coding practice. It doesn't even get the comment markup right.

Comment: @MichaelKay Fair enough, but it's a legacy code base.  I'd fixed a number of places by hand before realizing the problem was systemic.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be caused by mixed linking of conflicting versions of `libxml2` and `libxslt`  from another dependency.  The system versions:

```
libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
libxslt.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.26.0)
```

The bundled versions with pre-built Postgres 12:

```
libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.4.0)
libxslt.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.29.0)
```

If you get the e.g. the `libxml2` from Postgres but the `libxslt` from the system, then it mostly works but `disable-output-escaping` mysteriously breaks.  If you use either pair (both system, or both bundled with Postgres), then `disable-output-escaping` works.  You have to take into account the linker ordering (e.g. as reported by `otool -L` if more than one version is present.